# I can't build signed apk file in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I can't build a signed apk file, I am using a react-native-easy-starter kit.
But I am not sure what the issue is.

***Here is error message:***

```
yarn run v1.22.5 $ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED warning: the transform cache was reset. E:\3. tasks\2021-07-20 new React Native app\react-native-easy-starter-master\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:285 if (cb) cb.apply(this, arguments) ^

TypeError: cb.apply is not a function at E:\3. tasks\2021-07-20 new React Native app\react-native-easy-starter-master\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:285:20 at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:193:5)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'. Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 12s 26 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 24 up-to-date error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Edit the post and create a code snippet from that pic. Its barely readable

Comment: Hello @Programmerabc, I have edited my post.
It is cmd codes.
Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 1):

Try typing the following command

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```